# My dog won’t eat unless it is in my hand

Tags: dogs, behavior, diet

My dog is 11 months old and I just recently got him a few days ago from the shelter the first couple days he was eating out of his bowl and then today he just wouldn’t eat so I tried showing him his food my putting my hand in it and getting a hand full and he started eating it so I stopped and walked away and he would just follow me so I tried it again and he ate it out of my hand I don’t know if he thinks it’s a game we’re playing or what but now he won’t eat at all I tried feeding him again later toda and when I set the bowl down he pawed at my hand and started licking it we have been feeding him people food out of our hand so maybe that could be it but I’m not exactly sure anyone got a solution??